# Plotting a bump function

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I would like to plot a bump function in a similar way as its done in Loring W. Tu's Book 'An introduction to Manifolds' (page 129, fig. 13.4), however it never quite works the way I want. Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone} 

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\pgfplotsset{%
every x tick/.style={black, thick},
every y tick/.style={black, thick},
every tick label/.append style = {font=\footnotesize},
every axis label/.append style = {font=\footnotesize},
compat=1.12
  }
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xmin=-1.2, xmax=2, ymin=-0.7, ymax=1.2,

 xtick = {-1,0,1}, ytick = { 1},
 scale=0.4, restrict y to domain=-1.5:1.2,
 axis x line=center, axis y line= center,
 samples=40]


 \addplot[black, samples=100, smooth, domain=-1.2:0, thick]
   plot (\x, { 0 });

 \addplot[black, samples=100, smooth, domain=0:1, thick, label={x}]
   plot (\x, { exp( -1/\x)/(exp (-1/\x)+exp(1/(\x-1))) });


 \addplot[black, thick, samples=100, smooth, domain=1:2]
   plot (\x, {1} );

 \end{axis}
 \end{tikzpicture}

  \end{document}
```

My main problem with this result is, that the "plateau" is already attained before x=1, which really doesn't look like it's right. Changing sample sizes to higher than 100 will immediately yield dimension errors. Any tips?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Welcome to TeX.SE! I do not have that book but often people use `tanh` for that.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone} 

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\pgfplotsset{%
every x tick/.style={black, thick},
every y tick/.style={black, thick},
every tick label/.append style = {font=\footnotesize},
every axis label/.append style = {font=\footnotesize},
compat=1.12
  }
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xmin=-1.2, xmax=2, ymin=-0.7, ymax=1.2,
 xtick = {-1,0,1}, ytick = { 1},
 scale=0.4, restrict y to domain=-1.5:1.2,
 axis x line=center, axis y line= center,
 samples=40]


 \addplot[black, samples=100, smooth, domain=-1.2:2, thick]
   plot (\x, {0.5*(1+tanh(5*(\x-0.5)))});
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course, you can vary the width of the step by playing with the prefactor, which is 5 above.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,tikz]{standalone} 
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{%
every x tick/.style={black, thick},
every y tick/.style={black, thick},
every tick label/.append style = {font=\footnotesize},
every axis label/.append style = {font=\footnotesize},
compat=1.12
  }
\begin{document}
\foreach \X in {2,2.2,...,6,5.8,5.6,...,2.2}
{\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xmin=-1.2, xmax=2, ymin=-0.7, ymax=1.2,
 xtick = {-1,0,1}, ytick = { 1},
 scale=0.4, restrict y to domain=-1.5:1.2,
 axis x line=center, axis y line= center,
 samples=40,
 title={$f(x)=\left[1+\tanh\bigl(
 \pgfmathprintnumber[precision=1,fixed,zerofill]{\X}(x-1/2)\bigr)\right]/2$}]

 \addplot[black, samples=100, smooth, domain=-1.2:2, thick]
   plot (\x, {0.5*(1+tanh(\X*(\x-0.5)))});
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: great answer, exactly what I needed thanks a lot!

Comment: @ArtificialStupidity Well, fixed it, but do you think that is important here?

Comment: Yes. It is important for me. :-) Thank you for fixing!

Answer (score 4):

The plots in proferred answers do not look like what I understand to be a *bump* function; rather, the plots of the derivatives of the indicated functions would be bump functions. The following directly produces a bump function plot, with support the interval $[-1,1]$:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone} 

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\pgfplotsset{%
  every x tick/.style={black, thin},
  every y tick/.style={black, thick},
  every tick label/.append style = {font=\footnotesize},
  every axis label/.append style = {font=\footnotesize},
  compat=1.12
 }
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xmin=-1.2, xmax=1.2, ymin=-0.2, ymax=1.2,
  xtick = {-1,0,1}, ytick = { 1},
  scale=0.4, restrict y to domain=-0.2:1.2,
  axis x line=center, axis y line= center,
  samples=40]
\addplot[black, samples=100, smooth, domain=-1.2:-1, thick]
   plot (\x, { 0 });
\addplot[black, samples=100, smooth, domain=-1:1, thick, label={x}]
   plot (\x, {exp(1-1/(1-x^2)});
\addplot[black, thick, samples=100, smooth, domain=1:1.2]
   plot (\x, {0} );
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: Bump function]

(I'm unsure how to avoid the apparent gap in the graph immediately to the right of $x=-1$.)

Comment: The gap will disappear once you plot `\addplot[black, samples=101, smooth, domain=-1.2:1.2, thick, label={x}]
   plot (\x, {ifthenelse(abs(x)>1,0,exp(1-1/(1-x^2))});` instead of three plots.

Comment: @marmot: but why does the middle of the 3-part plot code fail to fill in just to the right of -1, even if I use `samples=101` for that portion? Is this just due to a rounding error?

Comment: No, the function is not defined there. LaTeX does not take limits. So you ask it to evaluate `exp(1-1/(1-x^2))` at `x=-1` and when LaTeX parses this, it just sees an infinity resulting from `-1/(1-x^2)` while it does not care whether or not the infinity means that the exponential will vanish. As a consequence, it drops this coordinate, and starts the plot at the next point. If you draw everything in one stretch, it will still drop these coordinates, but then connect two "well-behaved" points, so that there won't be a gap.